# Log file tracing tools

Tags: logging, log4j, notepad++, monitoring, trace

What are some practices, tools and tricks that can make the log file auditing and tracing more effective and pleasant experience when troubleshooting the cause of a bug?

Typically I copy the rows from application server log file (log4j) or database table (custom schema), and inspect the rows in notepad++, searching for the particular correlating log messages and timestamps.

But the log is very verbose, column positioning is lost, it strains eyes to find the correct timestamps, and the red thread is often lost in the information overload and clunky traversing.

I would like some tools which let me effectively traverse the log file programmatically and keep the grip of the red thread without pencil notes. I would especially like:

- Traverse rows in time intervals/criterias (for example next row after 20 minutes or last row of the day)
- Highlight rows with colors and attach bookmarks / notes to them
- Filter out certain rows with certain criteria
- Switch between different formatting / layouts at fly

In general I would like to have "intelligent assistance" to the log traversing workflow. Does such tools or plugins exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking exclusively for a Notepad++ plugin, but if not, you can try [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com). Looking at the requested features you listed here, it may be a good fit.

You may want to try these features: Calendar, Timeline, Filter. Since you seem to use Log4j to produce your logs, you may want to use a "Log4j/Logback pattern Parser" (see menu "File" > "Configure log parsers"): to create this Parser, just copy/paste your Pattern (the one you have specified in your log4j config file) in the Parser creation form.